# How to use python reference for encoding a bech32 address?

Tags: python, bech32-address, bip350-bech32m

Could someone provide an example of how to use the [python reference implementation](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/master/ref/python/segwit_addr.py) for generating a bech32 address?

For example, generating a mainnet bech32 address for this scriptPubKey: "0014751e76e8199196d454941c45d1b3a323f1433bd6"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference implementation provides a handy all-in-one encode function. To encode the scriptPubKey `0014751e76e8199196d454941c45d1b3a323f1433bd6` as a mainnet bech32 address, you would do:

```
import bech32
import binascii

spk = binascii.unhexlify('0014751e76e8199196d454941c45d1b3a323f1433bd6')
version = spk[0] - 0x50 if spk[0] else 0
program = spk[2:]
print(bech32.encode('bc', version, program))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Andrew's answer I recently used the above code snippet to generate bech32m addresses from P2TR scriptPubKeys.

I cloned the bech32 [repo](https://github.com/sipa/bech32) and then created a file for the code snippet in the `bech/ref/python` directory.

I took a P2TR scriptPubKey from the BIP 341 [test vectors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341/wallet-test-vectors.json) e.g. `5120712447206d7a5238acc7ff53fbe94a3b64539ad291c7cdbc490b7577e4b17df5`

Then this slightly adjusted code generated the associated bech32m address (`bc1pwyjywgrd0ffr3tx8laflh6228dj98xkjj8rum0zfpd6h0e930h6saqxrrm`).

```
import segwit_addr
import binascii

spk = binascii.unhexlify('5120712447206d7a5238acc7ff53fbe94a3b64539ad291c7cdbc490b7577e4b17df5')
version = spk[0] - 0x50 if spk[0] else 0
program = spk[2:]
print(segwit_addr.encode('bc', version, program))
```